# Spring Security 3 xml file

Tags: xml, spring, security, url, intercept

Please let me know what is the maximum size of Spring Security xml file with which I can run my application. Just wanted to know this because if an end user keeps on adding n number of intercept-url tag within it then upto what size I can run my application. Server/container should not fail while starting.

Comment: I would imagine you should be fine up to some ridiculous file size.  My questions to you are: Why are your 'users' able to change your spring-security xml files?  Have you considered that the application container may be failing due to actual wiring issues of your app?

Comment: Nothing like this one. Just want to understand how many intercept url pattern user will be allowed to write within Spring security xml file. It should not happen that due to large number of tags within xml file my application server should not come up.